# Access JSON data returned from CMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The CMS I am using will give me JSON data of each item within a database. I use the following code to access this data:

```
var items = new BCAPI.Models.WebApp.ItemCollection("Strain Bank");
items.fetch({
  success: function (items) {
    items.each(function (item) {
        item.fetch({
            success: function (itemDetails) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(itemDetails.attributes))
            }
        });
    });
  }
});
```

This `console.log(JSON.stringify(itemDetails.attributes))` outputs the following code for each item. An example of an items code is below:

```
{
    "id": 4441485,
    "name": "Alien OG",
    "fields": {
        "Buzz Length": "580",
        "Strength": "37",
        "Sativa Percentage": "231",
        "Overall Rating": "40",
        "Flower Time": "61",
        "Potency": "10",
        "Yield": "10",
        "Height": "20",
        "Reviews": "4",
        "Grow Reviews": "1",
        "Creative": "2",
        "Euphoric": "0",
        "Uplifted": "0",
        "Energetic": "2",
        "Lazy": "0",
        "Focused": "2",
        "Happy": "1",
        "Talkative": "0",
        "Giggly": "0",
        "Tingly": "0",
        "Hungry": "0",
        "Sleepy": "0",
        "Aroused": "0",
        "Migraines": "1",
        "Nausea": "0",
        "Insomnia": "0",
        "Pain": "2",
        "Anxiety": "0",
        "Stress": "2",
        "PMS": "0",
        "Lack of Appetite": "0",
        "Muscle Spasms": "0",
        "Depression": "2",
        "Seizures": "0",
        "Fatigue": "1",
        "Fruity": "0",
        "Citrus": "0",
        "Seasonings-Spicy": "1",
        "Floral": "2",
        "Pungent": "2",
        "Chemical": "1",
        "Earthy": "2",
        "Sweet": "0",
        "Grass": "1",
        "Skunky": "0"
    }
}
```

What I need to do is access the data within each item. I am unsure how to do this. I tried:

```
//Thecode below replaces console.log(JSON.stringify(itemDetails.attributes)) in the above example.

var json = JSON.stringify(itemDetails.attributes)
$.each($.parseJSON(json), function(idx, obj) {
console.log(obj.name);
});
```

When I try the above code I see two things in the `console.log`:

```
TypeError: obj is null
```

and

```
undefined
```

How do I properly access the JSON data?

Comment: what is the outcome of this..? `console.log(JSON.stringify(itemDetails.attributes))` ..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - See my edit just below the first block of code.

Comment: `outputs the following code for each item.` But we just need to see the entire JSON.. can you show us..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - I edited answer. What is there is what my CMS gives me. Note: I am not posting each items code here, just one item, they are identical to the example. The only difference is the data but the fields are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access data in each item by `.` notation, like `itemDetails.attributes.id`, `itemDetails.attributes.name` and `itemDetails.attributes.fields`

Replace below:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(itemDetails.attributes))
```

With below and try

```
console.log(itemDetails.attributes.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the desired object wrongly. Try,

```
$.each(xObj.fields, function (key, val) {
    console.log(key + " : " + val);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/gXfWM/)